# Are all linear PDE's separable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

New to partial differential equations and have not been able to come up with an example where a linear PDE is non separable.

Comment: On what domain?

Comment: What about du/dx + du/dt = 1 ?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Yes that works. Was not considering nonhomogeneity. Thanks!

Comment: @hunter2 There are many homogeneous examples as well. Like try adding a term $g(x,t)u$ where $g$ has dependence on both variables (and cannot be written as a sum of a function of x and a function of t).